# how to properly convert json for datatables

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, datatables

im new to json and im having a hard time figuring out how to compose my script so that i could display it using datatables

my json data looks like this

```
  {  "success": true,
    "data": {
        "events": {
            "My Event Name": {
                "date": "january 1, 2017",
                "place": "My Home",
                "participants": ["Merly", "Sonia"],
                "ideas": {
                    "this is an idea": {
                        "idea_detail": {
                            "deets": ["1.00", "1.00"]
                        },
                        "last_update": 1517977880
                    },
                    "another idea": {
                        "idea_detail": {
                            "deets": ["1.02", "12.00"]
                        },
                        "last_update": 1517977882
                    }
                },
                "info": {
                    "display_name": "Display",
                    "num": 2,
                    "date": 1517977921
                }
            },
            }
    }
}
```

upon researching, this is what i came up with:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$('#example').DataTable({ 
  'ajax'       : {
    "type"   : "POST",
    "url"    : "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/trial.txt",
    "dataSrc": function (json) {
      var return_data = new Array();
      var events = new Array();

var events = $.map(json.data.events, function(value, index) {
    return value;
}); 

      for(var i=0;i < events; i++){
        return_data.push({
          'event': json.data.events[i],
          'date': json.data.events[i].date,
          'place': json.data.events[i].place,
          'participants': json.data.events[i].participants,
          'ideas': json.data.events[i].ideas,
          'detail': json.data.events[i].ideas[i].idea_detail[i],
          'last_update': json.data.events[i].ideas.last_update,
          'info': json.data.events[i].info
        })
      }
      return return_data;
    }

    },
    "columns"    : [
    {'data': 'event'},   
    {'data': 'date'},
    {'data': 'place'},
    {'data': 'participants'},
    {'data': 'ideas'},
    {'data': 'detail'},
    {'data': 'last_update'},
    {'data': 'info'}  ]
})

} );
```

im probably doing all of this wrong, i hope someone could stir me in to the right direction. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Datatables expects an array of objects, which it looks like you are trying to build.  My first question is can you have the server code return the data in the proper format?  For Datatables to use it without modification you will need to format it more like this:

```
{  "success": true,
    "data": {
        "events": [

              { "event": "My Event Name",
                "date": "january 1, 2017",
                "place": "My Home",
                "participants": ["Merly", "Sonia"],
                "ideas": {
                    "this is an idea": {
                        "idea_detail": {
                            "deets": ["1.00", "1.00"]
                        },
                        "last_update": 1517977880
                    },
                    "another idea": {
                        "idea_detail": {
                            "deets": ["1.02", "12.00"]
                        },
                        "last_update": 1517977882
                    }
                },
                "info": {
                    "display_name": "Display",
                    "num": 2,
                    "date": 1517977921
                }
            },
           .....next record.....
         ]
    }
}
```

With this structure you can just set the ajax.dataSrc to this:  `dataSrc: "data.events"`.  And all you have to do is worry about how you want to display the `ideas`.

Depending on your requirements the `ideas` object seems to be a good candidate for [Row Details](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).  You can parse that object on the fly when the user wants to see it.

However, I think the source of your current problem at the moment is this:

```
for(var i=0;i < events; i++){
```

I think you want this:

```
for(var i=0;i < events.length; i++){
```

The next area is this:

```
'ideas': json.data.events[i].ideas,
'detail': json.data.events[i].ideas[i].idea_detail[i],
```

You would need a separate for loop to process each of the `ideas` into a structure that you want to display.  `.ideas[i].idea_detail[i]` will give you array index errors since `i` is not really looping through these parts of the object.

I would recommend ignoring the `ideas` part for the moment and just get the basic data to display.  Once you get that then we can discuss the `ideas`.  Need to know how you want it displayed and we can help you parse it appropriately.

Comment: thank you for your response, but in my case i can't edit the json data. im thinking of not using DataTables anymore and just iterate from the objects/arrays and get the values and display it in a list (ul / li) instead. but again, im not sure how to do it. this is what im thinking of using instead :

Comment: <script>$.getJSON('MY_JSON_URL', 
 function(data) { 
for(var i=0;i < events.length; i++){
        var list = `<li>Events: ${data.events}</li>`
}
        $(".mylist").html(list);
    });</script>

Comment: I think you just need to step through the data a little at a time.  Its a complex structure and will take a bit to work out what to do.  I started a small example for you here: http://live.datatables.net/henogaxu/1/edit .  I made a couple changes to your code, added some console.log statements and built a basic Datatable of the first level items.  Where it shows `[object Object]` in the table we need to further breakdown that object to display how you need.  Feel free to update the example.  Post back details of how you want `ideas` and `info` displayed if you want further help.

Comment: Checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48717998/7764175).  It has a similar json response as yours and uses the dataSrc to build the array.  Pretty simple solution but you will still need to figure out how to handle your nested objects; `ideas` and `info`.

Comment: thank you for your time, this is great ! http://live.datatables.net/henogaxu/1/edit  but one thing i noticed, i tried to add another 'events' record, but the table is not displaying the second record? what could be the problem?

Comment: I changed the loops some: http://live.datatables.net/henogaxu/4/edit.  The loop still needs to do something with `ideas`.  Currently the result is `[object Object]`.  How to modify the data depends on how you want to display it.

Comment: actually, this is how i want my data to be displayed : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yebnl.gif is there a simpler way to do this with the JSON data that i have?

Comment: This example might give you some ideas: http://live.datatables.net/kolomujo/1/edit